# Improving code in c (sparse matrix representation)

Tags: c, matrix, sparse-matrix, representation

I made this piece of code written in C which takes too long to run. Is there any way to improve it? 
What i want to do is to sum the values of each row and save the value in a vector. In this code, i1 is the value containing the row locations of a matrix, the columns and the associated value. i1 is not sorted.

```
while(a < 2*var)
{
    for (int c=0; c < 2*var; c++)
    {
        if (i1[c][0] == a)
        {
            diag[b] += i1[c][2];
        }
    }
    a = a+1;
    b = b+1;
}
```

Any idea or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow specializes in not working code. If you can confidently answer "yes" to all 6 questions in the [Code Review On-Topic Check](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then you could ask on [codereview.se].

Comment: The computational complexity of the code you have posted is `O(N^2)`. I am not able to see how it can be improved without knowing the structure of the data contained in the matrix. The strategy for improving the computational complexity will be heavily dependent on the assumptions one can make about the contents of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `b = a + const`, you could simply use `diag[i1[c][0] + const] += i1[c][2]` and reduce the complexity from O(N<sup>2</sup>) to O(N).

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `i1[c][0]` are integer types, you can change your nested loops into a single loop:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 2 * var; c++) {
    if (i1[c][0] >= a && i1[c][0] < 2 * var) {
        diag[b + (i1[c][0] - a)] += i1[c][2];
    }
}
b += 2 * var - a;
a = 2 * var;
```